# Are 6.90-9 trailer tires an obsolete size?

Tags: tires, trailer

I have when seems to be an older trailer (not sure of age) which has tires labelled "6.90-9". They are in OK condition but I was looking into getting a spare, and had trouble finding anything in this size at all. Is this an obsolete size? (If so, what does that even mean - have industry norms / standards changed?)

The only other markings that the numbers is the name "Carlisle". Numbers:

[image]

The lack of obvious replacements makes me wonder if the trailer or at least the wheels are even older than I thought. The age isn't a problem in itself, just that I don't want to be stuck without a spare or with hard to find parts over the years.

Note - the rims are the split type where the front & back halves bolt together. This also might indicate age, or at least I haven't seen that style on any boat or utility trailer I have experience with.

---

Edit: Thanks to people posting links with similar tires. I realized though my question wasn't exactly asking what I meant. [I had read the following on eTrailer](https://www.etrailer.com/question-252915.html):

> ...we do not currently carry the 9 inch wheels that these will fit.
>
> I recommend upgrading just a bit in tire size so that you can use a
>   wheel size that is more readily available.

which is what gave me the impression these could be obsolete. That's really what I was trying to figure out, whether this is no longer a common size and if so following their advice would be worthwhile in the long run..

Comment: Is there anyway to get an image of the side markings of your tires, then edit it into your question? We might see something you're missing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 good suggestion, I've added one.

Comment: [Try these.](https://express.google.com/u/0/product/7996705194641438483_7585675226125867457_123315587?utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=tu_cu&utm_content=eid-lsjeuxoeqt%2Ceid-vqiqlmovzs&gtim=CNzAj6uzkdjPGRDM68jTrOyajjIY8OyvISIDVVNEKOCKo-YFMIPL5jo&utm_campaign=123315587&gclid=Cj0KCQjw4-XlBRDuARIsAK96p3B1gq1YmyVs4WLBi2a8JVuuhGQYprwePFWdi6KSEWz9wijhQAAi3ggaAowXEALw_wcB)

Comment: [Or these, even.](https://www.amazon.com/Carlisle-Trail-Boat-Trailer-Tire/dp/B005O5Z182) ... but you realize, this actually makes this a shopping question?

Comment: [And a Google search link.](https://www.google.com/search?ei=rTm6XKaYHq62ggeJjrLgAg&q=carlisle+6.90-9+trailer+tires)